# while passing an object as argument, how to update its variables when using "yield"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, yield

When using the following code only for demonstrative purposes:

```py
from uuid import uuid4


class router(object):

    def route(self):

        res = response(jid=str(uuid4()))

        worker = resource()
        worker.dispatch(res)

        print '[jid: %s, status: %s]' % (res.jid, res.status)


class response(object):

    def __init__(self, jid):
        self.jid = jid
        self.status = 0


class resource(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.status = 200

    def dispatch(self, res):
        res.status = self.status
        rs = 'ok'
        #return rs
        yield rs


app = router()
app.route()
```

If using `return rs` instead of `yield rs` I can update the value of **status** within the `dispatch(self, res`) method of the **resource** class, out put is something like:

```
[jid: 575fb301-1aa9-40e7-a077-87887c8be284, status: 200]
```

But if using `yield rs` I can't update the value of  **status**, I am getting always the original value, example:

```
[jid: 575fb301-1aa9-40e7-a077-87887c8be284, status: 0]
```

Therefore I would like to know, how to update the object variables of an object passed as a reference, when using **yield**.

Comment: `res.status` => `rs.status` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate the generator. Otherwise the generator is not executed.

```
>>> def gen():
...     print(1)
...     yield 'blah'
...     print(2)
...
>>> g = gen() # No print (not executed)
>>> next(g)   # print 1, yield `blah`. execution suspended.
1
'blah'
```

Replace following line:

```
worker.dispatch(res)
```

with:

```
for rs in worker.dispatch(res):
    pass
```

or

```
next(worker.dispatch(res))
```

Comment: it is ok to always iterate in case sometimes I have a **yield** and others a **return** ?

Comment: @nbari, I don't understand what you mean `others a return`.

Comment: I mean that some times I will be using **yield** and others **return**, therefore, I was thinking to always use something like ``for _ in worker.dispatch(res): pass`` so that I can get the correct result, what do you think?

Comment: @nbari, Ok I see. When you use `return`, you can't the return value (unless the return value itself is an iterable object.)

Comment: @nbari, The point is that if you use `yield` in the function, the function become generator function. Call the generator function does not return value, but a generator. The generator is not executed until you iterate it or continue it using `next` function/method or `send` method.

Comment: I was testing **gevent** and came across this problem, but  since I am using this for a wsgi app, If I am right,  the application object must return an iterable yielding zero or more strings, so I think is safe to use your suggestion ``for _ in worker.dispatch(res): pass``

Comment: @nbari, Why do you bother to iterate it? If you use `return`, just use the return value. Choose `return` or `yield`. Then just use return value of iterate/next it accordingly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47248/discussion-between-nbari-and-falsetru)

Answer (score 2):

By using `yield` you are telling python that your `dispatch()` method is a generator.

So when you call `worker.dispatch(res)`, nothing actually happens (try to call `print worker.dispatch(res)`, you'll see just the object reference).

You have to iterate over it as mentioned by falsetru.

See also [the Python yield keyword explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)